# How can I implement DI/IoC for a repeated and variable process without creating kernels on demand?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

I know, this probably wins the award for longest and most confusing question title.  Allow me to explain...

I am trying to refactor a long-running batch process which, to be blunt, is extremely ugly right now.  Here are a few details on the hard specifications:

- The process must run several times (i.e. in the tens of thousands);
- Each instance of the process runs on a different "asset", each with its own unique settings;
- A single process consists of several sub-processes, and each sub-process requires a different slice of the asset's settings in order to do its job.  The groups are not mutually exclusive (i.e. some settings are required by multiple sub-processes).
- The entire batch takes a very long time to complete; thus, a single process is quite time-sensitive and performance is actually of far greater concern than design purity.

What happens now, essentially, is that for a given asset/process instance, a "Controller" object reads all of the settings for that asset from the database, stuffs them all into a strongly-typed settings class, and starts each sub-process individually, feeding it whichever settings it needs.

The problems with this are manifold:

- There are over 100 separate settings, which makes the settings class a ball of mud;
- The controller has way too much responsibility and the potential for bugs is significant;
- Some of the sub-processes are taking upwards of 10 constructor arguments.

So I want to move to a design based on dependency injection, by loosely grouping settings into different services and allowing sub-processes to subscribe to whichever services they need via constructor injection.  This way I should be able to virtually eliminate the bloated controller and settings classes.  I want to be able to write individual components like so:

```
public class SubProcess : IProcess
{
    public SubProcess(IFooSettings fooSettings, IBarSettings barSettings, ...)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The problem, of course, is that the "settings" are specific to a given asset, so it's not as simple as just registering `IFooSettings` in the IoC.  The injector somehow has to be aware of *which* `IFooSettings` it's supposed to use/create.

This seems to leave me with two equally unattractive options:

- Write every single method of `IFooSettings` to take an asset ID, and pass around the asset ID to every single sub-process.  This actually *increases* coupling, because right now the sub-processes don't need to know anything about the asset itself.
- Create a new IoC container for each full process instance, passing the asset ID into the constructor of the *container itself* so it knows which asset to grab settings for.  This feels like a major abuse of IoC containers, though, and I'm very worried about performance - I don't want to go and implement this and find out that it turned a 2-hour process into a 10-hour process.

Are there any other ways to achieve the design I'm hoping for?  Some design pattern I'm not aware of?  Some clever trick I can use to make the container inject the *specific* settings I need into each component, based on some kind of contextual information, without having to instantiate 50,000 containers?

Or, alternatively, is it actually OK to be instantiating this many containers over an extended period of time?  Has anybody done it with positive results?

Comment: @Aaronaught: Can you show more code about how your processes and sub processes look like and their interaction with each other and the controller. I tend to agree with the Factory approach suggested by Harper. If you can show more details I might be able to say something useful.

Comment: @Steven: I can try posting a simplified model/diagram, although we're talking about tens of thousands of lines of actual *code* here.  And the point of my comment to him is that *I agree with the Factory approach too*; the problem with his answer is that *that's what the IoC container is supposed to do, building my own completely defeats the purpose of using one at all.*

Comment: I actually just yesterday discovered [context variables](http://kohari.org/2008/03/13/context-variables-in-ninject/) in Ninject, which I've never used before, and I think these may fit the bill, so I might end up deleting this question or answering it myself...

Comment: @Aaronaught: Of course I'm not interested in all the code. Just enough code to be able to help you. However, if you think your problem is solved, my job is done ;-).

Comment: @Aaronaught: I must say that I never needed any complex features of any DI framework. The example of context variables seems overdone. If I am not mistaking, you can achieve the same with the following code: http://4kcan.com/s/MzQ1.

Comment: Sure @Steven, but that has no type safety whatsoever.  Part of the reason for using a DI Framework is so that you don't have write Reflection code like that.  You're making a lot of assumptions manually resolving a type name and personally, I wouldn't want to see that kind of thing in production code in one of my systems/sites. That said, there are simpler ways of accomplishing that specific task with Ninject 2 and MVC 2, but that example is from a few years ago. My scenario isn't quite as straightforward as resolving a controller name - as explained, the variable affects data, not just types.

Answer (score 1):

**MAJOR EDIT**

SettingsFactory: generates various Settings objects from the database on request.

SubProcessFactory: generates subprocesses on request from the controller.

Controller: iterates over assets, using the SettingsFactory and SubProcessFactory to create and launch the needed subprocesses.

Is this different than what you're doing? Not really from a certain angle, but very much from another. Separating these responsibilities into separate classes is important, as you've acknowledged. A DI container could be used to improve the flexibility of both Factory pieces. The implementation details are, in some ways, less critical than improving the design, because once the design is improved, implementation can vary more readily.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I still believe that this isn't really giving me any of the benefits of DI, namely the ability to design by contract and *remove* all of the controller/factory couplings.  This essentially amounts to a minor refactoring of the monolithic settings class into several individual classes, which is fine, but not the important part of what I'm trying to do, since I'd still have to write and maintain all of the factory and controller code instead of just using the IoC container to handle all of that plumbing.